# Rails not loading application.css

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, sass, haml

Css files aren't being loaded in at all in my development and I'm a bit confused why

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title Cohortboard
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    = yield
```

is my haml its the generated one, in my application.css.sass

```
/*
 *= require_self
 */

body {
  background: #f2f2f4;
}

@import "main/variables";
@import "styles/students";
```

Here's my development.rb file just in case it's interfering

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
end
```

when I load the webpage there are no styles loaded

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-14 13:23:46 -0700
Processing by StudentsController#home as HTML
Rendered students/home.html.haml (5.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 10.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

My controller wasn't inheriting from

> ApplicationController